# How to remember the derivatives of inverse trigonometry function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, soft-question, inverse

I remember the derivatives of trig functions  by naming 3x basic right triangles in a specific way and using ONE simple multiplication.  Just wondering if there are  similar approaches  to remember the derivatives of inverse trig function with the assisting of some basic triangles?
[image]

**Procedures $\to$**

1. Draw a right triangle (1, $\cos x,sinx$).Label its sides accordingly as shown in Fig.1.
2. Put the hypotenuse label ("1" in this case)  in side the triangle , name this triangle as "1" triangle.
3. Here is the only rule:  **|X'| = |Central value  *   Y|**, where X and Y are the  two functions on the NONE "1" sides.  In this case, the central value is "1", and the two functions on the NONE "1" sides are $sinx$ and $cos x$.
   **$           $|$sinx'| =|1* cos x$| ,  $|cosx'|= |1*sinx|$** (Fig.1)

Similarly, divide each side of "1"triangle by $sinx$ and $cosx$ to obtain "$sec"  and  “$cscx" triangles in Fig. 2 and Fig.3.

**$|secx'| =|secx*tanx|$,  $|tanx'|= sec*secx$**  (Fig.2)

**$|cscx'| =|cscx*cotx|$,  $|cotx'|= cscx*cscx$**  (Fig.3)

(Need to apply negative signs to get values for $cosx', cotx' $and $cscx'$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slight re-packaging of your mnemonic.

We start with the figure I call the Fundamental Trigonograph (the inspiration for my avatar!), whose segment-lengths correspond to the trig values associated with (acute) angle $\theta$.

[image]

Note that the "$1$" segment separates "ordinary" segments ($\sin$, $\tan$, $\sec$) from "complementary" segments ($\cos$, $\cot$, $\csc$).

Then, with no motivation whatsoever, we augment the figure with two right triangles having legs $\sec$ and $\csc$, and hypotenuses parallel to the "$1$" segment. (I've suppressed the "$1$" label to reduce visual clutter, but extended it to highlight the separation between "ordinaries" and "complementaries".)

One readily determines the new side lengths to be $\sec\tan$, $\sec^2$, $\csc\cot$, $\csc^2$; by interesting coincidence, lengths $\sin$ and $\cos$ appear in the lower-left quadrant in an obvious way. I've attached negative signs to the new segments on the "complementary" side of the augmented figure ... um ... *just because*. :)

[image]

With this, the rule is something like:
$$\text{A function and its derivative are "natural" perpendicular pairs on the same side of "$1$".}$$

That is,

- $\tan$ "naturally" pairs with $\sec^2$, and $\sec$ with $\sec\tan$. The pairing of the original $\sin$ segment with the augmenting $\cos$ segment is slightly contrived, but it works.
- Likewise, $\cot$, $\csc$, and $\cos$ "naturally" pair with $-\csc^2$, $-\csc\cot$, and $-\sin$.

---

Is this the *best* presentation of the mnemonic? I'm not sure ---it's just what occurred to me in the moment--- but I kinda like it. I especially like that it builds on the Fundamental Trigonograph, which *absolutely* belongs in every student's tool belt. (See, for instance, my still-drafty note ["(Almost) Everything You Need to Remember about Trig, in One Simple Diagram" (PDF link via tricochet.com)](http://tricochet.com/math/pdfs/AlmostEverythingAboutTrig.pdf). I may need to make an addition!)

Comment: Blue, I read your paper a few days ago, what a work  to pull all these together!  Just wonderful!  I have had some hard time to attach sign to my graph in a consistent way. I like your construction in the cool way to  arrange trig and its derivative in the perpendicular way.  (Not sure is how to be consistent with  the sign though.  For example, should cos be negative in quad2 and 3?)  Looking forward to your new addition, please keep me posted :-) Thanks!

Comment: @BrightStar: The signs don't reflect the effects on the values in the quadrants. They're just there to serve the mnemonic, since the derivatives of co-functions are negative. If it's confusing, you can leave them off of the diagram itself, and change the rule to "A function and its derivative are perpendicular, with a sign change for those on the complementary side of $1$".

Comment: I never tire of proselytizing the Fundamental Trigonograph. It was the subject of my (now-defunct) iPhone app [Trigger](https://tricochet.com/trigger/), and I've since listed [a poster of it on Etsy](https://etsy.com/listing/788311128) and even [a t-shirt on TeeSpring](https://teespring.com/fundamental-trigonograph). I *really* like that diagram! :)